# How to remove N items from list to be excluded from further processing

Tags: python, list

The code process a list by selecting random 3 items.

```
import random
myList = ['TGJG78', 'Y7ITHL', 'VHZK0C', '288C13', 'W1JKEK', 
          'JQ55C9', 'M1BN3S', 'G5B3YF', 'MW1RJ9', 'CS9PZ6', 
          '9LJ3IY', 'XLAMG0', 'BGWN3L', 'SL2BSX']  #14 items in list
print("Selected :", random.choices(myList, k=3))
```

How to exclude those that have been selected previously until all the items in the list is completed. Basically, I want to randomly groups the items in the list. In my list, the last group will just have 2 items.

Output:

```
Selected : ['MW1RJ9', 'Y7ITHL', 'M1BN3S']
```

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Do not expect `random.choices` to always select 3 different items. It can choose the same item multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

myList = ['TGJG78', 'Y7ITHL', 'VHZK0C', '288C13', 'W1JKEK', 
          'JQ55C9', 'M1BN3S', 'G5B3YF', 'MW1RJ9', 'CS9PZ6', 
          '9LJ3IY', 'XLAMG0', 'BGWN3L', 'SL2BSX']  #14 items in list

random.shuffle(myList)
n = 3 # group size

for i in range(0,len(myList),n):
    group = myList[i:i+n]
    print(group)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use random.shuffle to shuffle the list, then use the itertools.batched() to group the list. That is a new function since 3.12.
In case you are using older version of python, you can make a function:

```py
import itertools
def batched(iterable, n):
    """New in version 3.12 -> itertools.batched
    Batch data into tuples of length n. The last batch may be shorter."""
    # batched('ABCDEFG', 3) --> ABC DEF G
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError('n must be at least one')
    it = iter(iterable)
    while batch := tuple(itertools.islice(it, n)):
        yield batch

import random
def shuffled(iterable):
    copy = iterable[:]
    random.shuffle(copy)
    return copy

myList = ['TGJG78', 'Y7ITHL', 'VHZK0C', '288C13', 'W1JKEK', 
          'JQ55C9', 'M1BN3S', 'G5B3YF', 'MW1RJ9', 'CS9PZ6', 
          '9LJ3IY', 'XLAMG0', 'BGWN3L', 'SL2BSX']  #14 items in list

for batch in batched(shuffled(myList), 3):
    print(batch)
```

Example output:

```
('SL2BSX', 'BGWN3L', 'VHZK0C')
('9LJ3IY', 'G5B3YF', 'TGJG78')
('JQ55C9', 'W1JKEK', 'CS9PZ6')
('Y7ITHL', '288C13', 'XLAMG0')
('MW1RJ9', 'M1BN3S')
```

Comment: Nice use of the new `batched` function! I modified the "shuffle logic" by rolling it into its own function so that the original list remains unmodified.

Answer (score -1):

> *"... How to exclude those that have been selected previously until all the items in the list is completed. ..."*

You'll need to make a *deep-copy* of the *list* first; presuming, you want to maintain the original values.

Utilize the *[copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)* *module*, to obtain a *deep-copy*.
And, the *[random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)* module, to shuffle the *list*.

From here, utilize a *[generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators)*, to deduct the values; optionally shuffling on each call.

```py
import copy as c, random as r
a = ['TGJG78', 'Y7ITHL', 'VHZK0C', '288C13', 'W1JKEK',
     'JQ55C9', 'M1BN3S', 'G5B3YF', 'MW1RJ9', 'CS9PZ6',
     '9LJ3IY', 'XLAMG0', 'BGWN3L', 'SL2BSX']
b = c.deepcopy(a)

def remove(N: int):
    r.shuffle(b)
    s = b[:N]
    del b[:N]
    return s
```

Here is an example usage.

```py
print(remove(3))
print(remove(3))
print(remove(3))
print(remove(3))
print(remove(3))
```

Output

```
['288C13', 'JQ55C9', '9LJ3IY']
['Y7ITHL', 'BGWN3L', 'VHZK0C']
['W1JKEK', 'M1BN3S', 'XLAMG0']
['CS9PZ6', 'SL2BSX', 'TGJG78']
['G5B3YF', 'MW1RJ9']
```